# SQL automatically filtering results

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the query I'm trying to execute

```
select top(50)
plr_fullnm as Player,
concat('[b]',runs,'[/b]') as Runs,
balls as Balls,
frs as Frs,
sxs as Sxs,
round(sr,2) as StrikeRt,
team as Team,
opnt as Opposition,
ground as Ground,
concat ('Match # ',mat_no) as Scoreboard
from InningWiseBatRecords
order by runs desc, sr asc
```

These are top 4 rows from resulted data

```
Player          Runs        Balls   Frs Sxs StrikeRt    Team        Opposition  Ground      Scoreboard
Shai Hope       [b]98[/b]   137     10  0   71.53       WEST INDIES INDIA       Banglore    Match # 16
Kieron Pollard  [b]97[/b]   85      9   1   114.12      WEST INDIES PAKISTAN    Jamaica     Match # 14
Rohit Sharma    [b]97[/b]   83      9   3   116.87      INDIA       PAKISTAN    Mumbai      Match # 19
Virat Kohli     [b]95[/b]   68      12  4   139.71      INDIA       PAKISTAN    Mumbai      Match # 19
```

But basically there are 7 more entries where runs is greater than 100, but I don't know somehow those rows keep getting discarded.

Wait it got solved by when I altered last statement from code to this

```
order by InningWiseBatRecords.runs desc, InningWiseBatRecords.sr asc
```

Why not calling the column name by its table name should have caused the problem though?

Comment: Maybe because you only get the top 50? Try increasing it to 57 or higher.

Comment: What is the data type of runs?

Comment: Strings and and numerical data types don't have the same ordering. `'97'` is **greater** than `'100'`. If you need to order values numerically, use a numerical data type.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `runs` in the ORDER BY clause binds to the expression `Runs` in the SELECT list, which is a `varchar`, and so is sorted as a string.  So `'[b]98[/b]'` > `'[b]100[/b]'`.

If you want to ORDER BY the table columns instead of the SELECT expression, qualify the expression in the ORDER BY, eg:

```
select top(50)
plr_fullnm as Player,
concat('[b]',runs,'[/b]') as Runs,
balls as Balls,
frs as Frs,
sxs as Sxs,
round(sr,2) as StrikeRt,
team as Team,
opnt as Opposition,
ground as Ground,
concat ('Match # ',mat_no) as Scoreboard
from InningWiseBatRecords r
order by r.runs desc, sr asc
```